# Passing in an array value into JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating an email app that sends messages to other people.  Currently, I have it working except for the recipients column. Right now, I hard-coded an email into the recipients column to get it working.  The reason is, is the recipients field is supposed to be an array.

What's the best way of passing a value from a user form (multiple addresses separated by commas) into JSON format?

Below is how I have it now.

Thanks!

```
const element = document.getElementById('sendEmail');
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'card51short@gmail.com',
      subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
      body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can't you make it an array directly? ```{recipients: ['card51short@gmail.com','card51short2@gmail.com'],
subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value }```

Comment: is value like a string separated  by comma and you need to convert this value to array?

Comment: Questions asking about "the best way" are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. The best way is often different based on your use case. It's unclear what you're having difficulty with. You have not shown an attempt to pass the email list to the backend. There are different ways to do it. It could be a comma/space separated string or it could be an array and the first two comments mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const element = document.getElementById('sendEmail');
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {

    const emailsFromForm = [ // NEW
      document.querySelector('#email1').value, // NEW
      document.querySelector('#email2').value // NEW
    ] // NEW

    fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: emailsFromForm, // EDITED
      subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
      body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
  });
}
```